# VB.Net equivalent for Java Rijndael decryption method

Tags: java, vb.net, rijndael

I have a working java decryption function displayed below.  The java source code for the RijndaelAlgorithm is the standard code you see all over the internet - for example:

http://www.opensymphony.com/oscore/api/com/opensymphony/module/random/Rijndael_Algorithm.html

I am trying to reproduce this function using VB.Net.  I know .Net has support for Rijndael, but I haven't found a combination that produces the same decrypted password as my java code below.   Seems like such a simple task but I have already spent days researching this.

Can anyone show me or direct me to sample code in VB.Net that would produce a function equivalent to the java function?

here are my arguments:

```
t = f8d44...cf22f8a     32 total characters 
keyArray = [113,64,51,102,120...98,98,108,115]  32 total bytes
keySize = 32
blockSize = 16
```

Here is my working java function:

```
public static String decrypt(String t, byte[] keyArray, int keySize, int blockSize)  
{
        StringBuffer plain = new StringBuffer(t.length());
        byte[] textBytes = RijndaelAlgorithm.getBytes(t);
        int cipherLen = textBytes.length;

        Object key = RijndaelAlgorithm.makeKey(setKeyLength(keyArray, keySize), keySize);

        for (int offset = 0; offset < cipherLen; offset += blockSize)
        {
              byte[] plainBytes = RijndaelAlgorithm.blockDecrypt(textBytes, offset, key, blockSize);

              plain.append(new String(plainBytes));
        }
        return plain.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may get some hints from the source code here:  http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I use these two functions in VB.NET, hope this helps

This is how I consume these functions

```
_ConnectionString = RijndaelSimple.Decrypt(_ConnectionString, RijndaelPhrase, CurrentSession.ApplicationSession.Application.ApplicationGuid.ToString.ToLower, "SHA1", 2, RijndaelVector, 128)





Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO

' <summary>
' This class uses a symmetric key algorithm (Rijndael/AES) to encrypt and 
' decrypt data. As long as encryption and decryption routines use the same 
' parameters to generate the keys, the keys are guaranteed to be the same.
' The class uses static functions with duplicate code to make it easier to 
' demonstrate encryption and decryption logic. In a real-life application, 
' this may not be the most efficient way of handling encryption, so - as 
' soon as you feel comfortable with it - you may want to redesign this class.
' </summary>

Public Class RijndaelSimple

' <summary>
' Encrypts specified plaintext using Rijndael symmetric key algorithm
' and returns a base64-encoded result.
' </summary>
' <param name="plainText">
' Plaintext value to be encrypted.
' </param>
' <param name="passPhrase">
' Passphrase from which a pseudo-random password will be derived. The 
' derived password will be used to generate the encryption key. 
' Passphrase can be any string. In this example we assume that this 
' passphrase is an ASCII string.
' </param>
' <param name="saltValue">
' Salt value used along with passphrase to generate password. Salt can 
' be any string. In this example we assume that salt is an ASCII string.
' </param>
' <param name="hashAlgorithm">
' Hash algorithm used to generate password. Allowed values are: "MD5" and
' "SHA1". SHA1 hashes are a bit slower, but more secure than MD5 hashes.
' </param>
' <param name="passwordIterations">
' Number of iterations used to generate password. One or two iterations
' should be enough.
' </param>
' <param name="initVector">
' Initialization vector (or IV). This value is required to encrypt the 
' first block of plaintext data. For RijndaelManaged class IV must be 
' exactly 16 ASCII characters long.
' </param>
' <param name="keySize">
' Size of encryption key in bits. Allowed values are: 128, 192, and 256. 
' Longer keys are more secure than shorter keys.
' </param>
' <returns>
' Encrypted value formatted as a base64-encoded string.
' </returns>
Public Shared Function Encrypt(ByVal plainText As String, _
                               ByVal passPhrase As String, _
                               ByVal saltValue As String, _
                               ByVal hashAlgorithm As String, _
                               ByVal passwordIterations As Integer, _
                               ByVal initVector As String, _
                               ByVal keySize As Integer) _
                       As String

    ' Convert strings into byte arrays.
    ' Let us assume that strings only contain ASCII codes.
    ' If strings include Unicode characters, use Unicode, UTF7, or UTF8 
    ' encoding.
    Dim initVectorBytes As Byte()
    initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector)

    Dim saltValueBytes As Byte()
    saltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue)

    ' Convert our plaintext into a byte array.
    ' Let us assume that plaintext contains UTF8-encoded characters.
    Dim plainTextBytes As Byte()
    plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText)

    ' First, we must create a password, from which the key will be derived.
    ' This password will be generated from the specified passphrase and 
    ' salt value. The password will be created using the specified hash 
    ' algorithm. Password creation can be done in several iterations.
    Dim password As PasswordDeriveBytes
    password = New PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, _
                                       saltValueBytes, _
                                       hashAlgorithm, _
                                       passwordIterations)

    ' Use the password to generate pseudo-random bytes for the encryption
    ' key. Specify the size of the key in bytes (instead of bits).
    Dim keyBytes As Byte()
    keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keySize / 8)

    'Dim keyBytes2 As Byte()
    'keyBytes2 = password.Rfc2898DeriveBytes

    ' Create uninitialized Rijndael encryption object.
    Dim symmetricKey As RijndaelManaged
    symmetricKey = New RijndaelManaged()

    ' It is reasonable to set encryption mode to Cipher Block Chaining
    ' (CBC). Use default options for other symmetric key parameters.
    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC

    ' Generate encryptor from the existing key bytes and initialization 
    ' vector. Key size will be defined based on the number of the key 
    ' bytes.
    Dim encryptor As ICryptoTransform
    encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes)

    ' Define memory stream which will be used to hold encrypted data.
    Dim memoryStream As MemoryStream
    memoryStream = New MemoryStream()

    ' Define cryptographic stream (always use Write mode for encryption).
    Dim cryptoStream As CryptoStream
    cryptoStream = New CryptoStream(memoryStream, _
                                    encryptor, _
                                    CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    ' Start encrypting.
    cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length)

    ' Finish encrypting.
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()

    ' Convert our encrypted data from a memory stream into a byte array.
    Dim cipherTextBytes As Byte()
    cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray()

    ' Close both streams.
    memoryStream.Close()
    cryptoStream.Close()

    ' Convert encrypted data into a base64-encoded string.
    Dim cipherText As String
    cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes)

    ' Return encrypted string.
    Encrypt = cipherText
End Function

' <summary>
' Decrypts specified ciphertext using Rijndael symmetric key algorithm.
' </summary>
' <param name="cipherText">
' Base64-formatted ciphertext value.
' </param>
' <param name="passPhrase">
' Passphrase from which a pseudo-random password will be derived. The 
' derived password will be used to generate the encryption key. 
' Passphrase can be any string. In this example we assume that this 
' passphrase is an ASCII string.
' </param>
' <param name="saltValue">
' Salt value used along with passphrase to generate password. Salt can 
' be any string. In this example we assume that salt is an ASCII string.
' </param>
' <param name="hashAlgorithm">
' Hash algorithm used to generate password. Allowed values are: "MD5" and
' "SHA1". SHA1 hashes are a bit slower, but more secure than MD5 hashes.
' </param>
' <param name="passwordIterations">
' Number of iterations used to generate password. One or two iterations
' should be enough.
' </param>
' <param name="initVector">
' Initialization vector (or IV). This value is required to encrypt the 
' first block of plaintext data. For RijndaelManaged class IV must be 
' exactly 16 ASCII characters long.
' </param>
' <param name="keySize">
' Size of encryption key in bits. Allowed values are: 128, 192, and 256. 
' Longer keys are more secure than shorter keys.
' </param>
' <returns>
' Decrypted string value.
' </returns>
' <remarks>
' Most of the logic in this function is similar to the Encrypt 
' logic. In order for decryption to work, all parameters of this function
' - except cipherText value - must match the corresponding parameters of 
' the Encrypt function which was called to generate the 
' ciphertext.
' </remarks>
Public Shared Function Decrypt(ByVal cipherText As String, _
                               ByVal passPhrase As String, _
                               ByVal saltValue As String, _
                               ByVal hashAlgorithm As String, _
                               ByVal passwordIterations As Integer, _
                               ByVal initVector As String, _
                               ByVal keySize As Integer) _
                       As String

    ' Convert strings defining encryption key characteristics into byte
    ' arrays. Let us assume that strings only contain ASCII codes.
    ' If strings include Unicode characters, use Unicode, UTF7, or UTF8
    ' encoding.
    Dim initVectorBytes As Byte()
    initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector)

    Dim saltValueBytes As Byte()
    saltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue)

    ' Convert our ciphertext into a byte array.
    Dim cipherTextBytes As Byte()
    cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText)

    ' First, we must create a password, from which the key will be 
    ' derived. This password will be generated from the specified 
    ' passphrase and salt value. The password will be created using
    ' the specified hash algorithm. Password creation can be done in
    ' several iterations.
    Dim password As PasswordDeriveBytes
    password = New PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, _
                                       saltValueBytes, _
                                       hashAlgorithm, _
                                       passwordIterations)

    ' Use the password to generate pseudo-random bytes for the encryption
    ' key. Specify the size of the key in bytes (instead of bits).
    Dim keyBytes As Byte()
    keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keySize / 8)

    ' Create uninitialized Rijndael encryption object.
    Dim symmetricKey As RijndaelManaged
    symmetricKey = New RijndaelManaged()

    ' It is reasonable to set encryption mode to Cipher Block Chaining
    ' (CBC). Use default options for other symmetric key parameters.
    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC

    ' Generate decryptor from the existing key bytes and initialization 
    ' vector. Key size will be defined based on the number of the key 
    ' bytes.
    Dim decryptor As ICryptoTransform
    decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes)

    ' Define memory stream which will be used to hold encrypted data.
    Dim memoryStream As MemoryStream
    memoryStream = New MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes)

    ' Define memory stream which will be used to hold encrypted data.
    Dim cryptoStream As CryptoStream
    cryptoStream = New CryptoStream(memoryStream, _
                                    decryptor, _
                                    CryptoStreamMode.Read)

    ' Since at this point we don't know what the size of decrypted data
    ' will be, allocate the buffer long enough to hold ciphertext;
    ' plaintext is never longer than ciphertext.
    Dim plainTextBytes As Byte()
    ReDim plainTextBytes(cipherTextBytes.Length)

    ' Start decrypting.
    Dim decryptedByteCount As Integer
    decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, _
                                           0, _
                                           plainTextBytes.Length)

    ' Close both streams.
    memoryStream.Close()
    cryptoStream.Close()

    ' Convert decrypted data into a string. 
    ' Let us assume that the original plaintext string was UTF8-encoded.
    Dim plainText As String
    plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, _
                                        0, _
                                        decryptedByteCount)

    ' Return decrypted string.
    Decrypt = plainText
End Function
```

End Class

Comment: I think part of what is confounding me is that my working java function does not make any reference to initialization Vectors.  But most of the Vb.net Code I have seen requires one -including yours.   I am trying to find a VB.Net sample that is equivalent to the java function I posted.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi Curitre: Post your question in Freelancer.com, Elance.com or oDesk.com . I am sure that someone will solve your problem for a few bucks. This worked for me many a time.